# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser kaios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scripts

I have updated my project to use the last versions of node and yarn, after this upgrade now my react project doesn't want to work with "browserslist".

I run "yarn start" and get this error:

```
./src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.2.0 (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.2.0)
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser kaios
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I have the following versions:

- node v10.15.3
- npm 6.9.0
- yarn v1.15.2

And my package.json its

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.2",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.5",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "plotly.js": "1.47.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-currency-format": "1.0.0",
    "react-dates": "18.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-excel-workbook": "0.0.4",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-plotly.js": "2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-select": "2.1.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.1",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "weather-icons": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --max-old-space-size=8192 start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">1%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

For me the issue it's related to css-loader, I try solving the issue and add css-loader@2.1.1 to the package.json. I try with other solution but no ones work.

Comment: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/365

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**TL;DR** `rm yarn.lock; yarn`

The long prose:

Both `browserslist` and `postcss-preset-env` might be 2nd level (deep) dependencies. This is quite common with `create-react-app`. However, `yarn upgrade` does not upgrade locked sub-dependencies and a command to do that is against philosophy of yarn.

Arguably, one of these libraries should  restrict required dependency version, and leave it to yarn to resolve good version. If that's the case, then `yarn` is correct.

It may be possible to resolve this by making some of `{browserslist, caniuse-lite, postcss-preset-env}` direct [dev] dependencies of your project.

Or, shorter, `rm yarn.lock; yarn` ✨

References:

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4986
- https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/365
- https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1184

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue and by fixing the version of `caniuse-lite` in the `package.json` with the previous to the last version I was able to workaround the issue.

Append to the `package.json`

```
  "resolutions": {
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30000957"
  },
```

Run `$ yarn`

And check that the `yarn.lock` is using the expected version:

```
...
caniuse-lite@1.0.30000957, caniuse-lite@^1.0.0, caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000939, caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000955, caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000957:
  version "1.0.30000957"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/caniuse-lite/-/caniuse-lite-1.0.30000957.tgz#fb1026bf184d7d62c685205358c3b24b9e29f7b3"
  integrity sha512-8wxNrjAzyiHcLXN/iunskqQnJquQQ6VX8JHfW5kLgAPRSiSuKZiNfmIkP5j7jgyXqAQBSoXyJxfnbCFS0ThSiQ==
...
```

Comment: This is good.  It is a much simpler and more precise solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I took a look into the code and it's because the update of `caniuse` which support query for Kai OS(some mobile OS in India I guess?)So if you add `postcss-preset-env` today and have `caniuse-lite` as a dependency of some packages installed before, you may encounter error

tl;dr
remove node_modules and lock then install all dependency again

Comment: Although KaiOS is not based in India, it's the 2nd most popular OS in India (according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KaiOS)

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error today. Seems like the issue is related to `postcss-preset-env`. Removing it form the list of postcss plugins solved my problem.

I decided to stay with `autoprofixer` and `postcss-custom-properties` instead of `postcss-preset-env`.

Comment: Please post more details or sample config

Comment: Actually, the chosen answer will be okay. Just remove yarn.lock. In my case, I struggled with the error, because I had installed `postcss-preset-env` right in the day when this error occurred. I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you upgrading to Create React App 3, this error is caused by an incompatibility with `browserslist@<4.5.5` and `caniuselite@>1.0.30000957` running together.

Run `npm ls browserslist` to see where older versions of `browserslist` are installed and upgrade those packages that have dependencies on `browserslist`

Yarn users can solve this by following some of the existing answers provided.

I'm an NPM user and solved this by installing `browserslist@^4.5.5` as a root dependency, and thus transitive `browserslist` dependencies are deduped to the root.